# Shotwell won't start after restoring my home folder

Tags: shotwell

I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 but had issues that meant I decided to return to 12.04.

I did a full reinstall formatting the drive and then used back-in-time to restore the home folders (last snapshot was made in 14.04).

Everything seems to work except Shotwell. I tried reinstalling and still get the same error. When running shotwell from terminal I get the error:

```
unique-gdbus-warning **: error while sending message: timeout was reached
```

Sometimes I was able to get shotwell to open but then it immediately stopped responding.

I have also tried using a different photo management app (darktable) and it also gave the same error.

Comment: Upgrading to 14.04 LTS through 'Software Updater' was like a breeze in my system with all apps. I would suggest you to do a fresh install/upgrade again to 14.04.

Comment: @bluepearlsky The OP already did that.

Comment: @user310345: There might be some old configuration files from your home folder restoration that are causing issues with a more recent Shotwell release. You could try renaming all shotwell-related folders in your home directory and then see if anything has changed. To find the folders in question use `locate shotwell` and look for entries located in your home folder (e.g. `/home/user/.shotwell` or `/home/user/gconf/apps/shotwell`).

Comment: @Glutanimate: I also suspected some old configuration file in the home folder and used locate to find these folders, removed them all, removed shotwell and reinstalled. New install still gave the same issues.

Comment: I installed the latest updates and shotwell is now functioning correctly.